# Laravel - for some reason, max breaks my query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this piece of code:

```
$query = Student::whereHas('statusuri', function($q) use ($status) {
                    $q->latest('status_student.id')->take(1)
                    ->where('status_id', $status)
                    ->whereNotNull('status_id');
                });
```

and it works fine, but I don't necessarily get the desired result.

I tried changing the first line to max (so I don't filter all my records then do a limit 1), I just get the highest ID from the beginning - like this:

```
$query = Student::whereHas('statusuri', function($q) use ($status) {
                    $q->max('status_student.id')
                    ->where('status_id', $status)
                    ->whereNotNull('status_id');
                });
```

but then my query breaks.

For some reason, I get this:

```
Unknown column 'students.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select max(`status_student`.`id`) as aggregate from `statusuri` inner join `status_student` on `statusuri`.`id` = `status_student`.`status_id` where `students`.`id` = `status_student`.`student_id`)
```

Why does my query break after I do this change?

Thanks.

```
Tables:
students
id bigint(20)
//other non-related data

statusuri
id  bigint(20) 
nume VARCHAR(255)

status_student
id int(11)
student_id int(10)
status_id int(10)
stare_stagiu_id int(11)
created_at timestamp
updated_at timestamp
```

statusuri() from Student

```
public function statusuri()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Status::class, 'status_student')
            ->withPivot('id', 'data_inceput', 'data_sfarsit', 'document', 'status_id', 'stare_stagiu_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Status and StatusStudent classes

```
class StatusStudent extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'status_student';
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'student_id', 'status_id', 'stare_stagiu_id'];
}

class Status extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'statusuri';

    public $fillable = ['nume'];

}
```

Comment: First off, what are you trying to do? Second, "students", I would suspect is what your Student model points towards in the database, does it contain an id column?

Comment: @Stoff Yes, my Student model contains an ID column. I'm trying to do a filter. You can check my last two posts (bseides this one).

Comment: Sorry, but you have to include the information in this question, not refer to something else. In this case, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, as such there is no way for me to help here. But generally speaking, when you're having issues. Include table structure and test data, show what you've done and explain what the expected outcome is. At that point, we can help further. Also, your first query that works but might not give the desired result is just confusing. Why include it if it is wrong?

Comment: @Stoff Because for this specific post I was strictly looking into why would max breaks my query :) I didn't want to include data from any other post, because it is not related. For this question I consider enough info, because I just changed from latest() to max() and the fields are just the same - there would be no reason (in my opinion) for it not to work.

Comment: The problem is that without giving us the tables, we cannot reacreate the environment locally.It's and odd error as it states that the column does not exist, and without recreating this myself I could not even begin to know what the issue is.

Comment: @Stoff okay - I will add it in an edit :)

Comment: @Stoff I added the tables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243560/discussion-between-octavian-niculescu-and-stoff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relations are messed up. The query is trying to use a column from the student table, but the student table is not available in said query as it is not joined. See this fiddle to see what goes wrong in the SQL.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52c96fa/6
In the end, I'd do it like this if I understood you correctly:

In StatusStudent.php (Model):

```
public function student() {
    return $this->hasOne(Student::class, 'id', 'student_id');
}
```

In Controller:

```
public function stackoverflowtest() {
    //Set teststatus
    $status = 1;

    //Get the latest status of all users - and if that status is correct, retrieve into array
    $latest = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT max(id) as id, student_id FROM status_student group by student_id"));
    $array = [];
    foreach ($latest as $l) {
        $status_id = StatusStudent::whereId($l->id)->whereStatusId($status)->first();
        if ($status_id) {
            array_push($array, $status_id);
        }
    }

    //$array now holds all the StatusStudent, simply user ->student to get the student related to said status, example below 
    if($array) {
        dd($array[0]->student);
        return $array;
    } else {
        return 'No match';
    }
}
```

First, we get all latest records for each user IF the status is correct. Then, we simply get the Student from the status_student table via the relation.